# c++ implement "Class<? entends C>"

Tags: java, c++

in java,i can use `Class<? extends C>` to represent a class which is a subclass of C.

es.
`void Test(Class<? entends C>)`

But, how to implement this by cpp??

I know the cpp template,es:

`template<class C>`

but it can not point a subclass of some classes

Comment: Just because the syntax looks similar doesn't mean you necessarily want a template. From your description, it could be as simple as `void Test(BaseClass& obj);` for an abstract type `BaseClass`.

Comment: @juanchopanza The second answer in the recently applied duplicate answered the OP's question correctly IMO.

Comment: If I understand your correctly (I'm not Javanese), the syntax in Java means that a certain *object* must be of *any type* that is derived from a certain *base class* `C`. Correct?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Really? I didn't think there was enough detail in the question to determine that.

Comment: @juanchopanza Yeah, it's unclear if OP want's to have a template here at all.

Answer (score 2):

There are three things that come to mind.

1. **Polymorphism**: simply take as function argument a reference or pointer to the base class `C`.

   ```
   void test(C const&obj)
   {
     /*
        manipulate the object through the public interface of C
        implemented via virtual functions
     */
   }

   struct D:C { /* ... */ } d;    // object of class derived from C
   test(d);
   ```
2. A **`template`** using [SFINAE](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) or [`static_assert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert) in combination with [`std::is_base_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of)

   ```
   template<typename T>
   std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<C,T>::value>
   test(T const&obj)
   { /* ... */ }

   template<typename T>
   void test(T const&obj)
   {
     static_assert(std::is_base_of<C,T>::value>,"T not derived from C");
     /* ... */
   }
   ```
3. In the future, we may have [**constraints and concepts**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints)

   ```
   template<typename T>
   requires std::Derived<T,C>
   void test(T const&obj)
   {
     /* ... */
   }
   ```

Comment: thank you very much